# Updating react grid layout using redux onLayoutChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-grid-layout

I have a react grid layout and am using redux to manage the state of my grid elements. I can add grid items with the content I want, and they can be moved around the grid and resized the way I want them to. The issue is that when I change the grid size or position, it is not updating the state in the redux store,  therefore when I leave the dashboard page and return to it, the grid objects reset to their initial state. I want to use an action to updateLayout, and have tried to do so in the following manor, although when I try and console log my layout I see it has not updated.

Here are my reducers including the addItem:

```
const initialState = {
    layout: [],
    count:[],
};


const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_GRID_ITEM:
            const id = uuid()
            console.log("adding: " + id)
            return{
                ...state,
                count: state.count.concat(<CreateGraph/>),
                layout: state.layout.concat({
                    i: `${id}`,
                    x: 2,
                    y: 0,
                    w: 4,
                    h: 5
                }),
            }

        case actionTypes.UPDATE_LAYOUT:            
            const updateLayout = (key, value) => {
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    state,
                    {
                        [key]: value,
                    },
                );
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                updateLayout
                
            }
            

    }
    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

And here is the code for my react grid layout. I want to update the layout every time the layout is changed - which can be done using the onLayoutChange attribute.

```
const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

const Dash = (props) => {
  const layout = props.layout
  const { value, addItem, updateLayout } = props
  const ref = useRef()

  const onLayoutChange = (layout, layouts) => {
    props.updateLayout("layouts", layouts)
    console.log(...props.layout)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
        <ReactGridLayout
          {...props}
          className="layout"
          layouts={props.layout}
          onLayoutChange={(layout, layouts => onLayoutChange(layout, layouts))}
          breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
          cols={{ lg: 12, md: 12, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
          resizeHandles={['s', 'w', 'e', 'n', 'sw', 'nw','se', 'ne']}
          verticalCompact={false}
          draggableHandle=".dragHandle"
               
      >        
        {_.map(value, (item, i) => (
          <div id = 'gridID' ref={ref} key={i} data-grid={props.layout[i]}>
            <span className='dragHandle'>Drag From Here</span>
            <br/>
            <DashItem  key={i} >
              {item}
            </DashItem>
            <span className='dragHandle'>Drag From Here</span>
          </div>
        ))}
        </ReactGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}


Dash.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.array,
  onIncreaseClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    value: state.count,
    layout: state.layout,
    onLayoutChange: state.onLayoutChange,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { 
  return {
    addItem: () => dispatch({type: actionTypes.ADD_GRID_ITEM}),
    updateLayout: (key, value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.UPDATE_LAYOUT, key, value})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dash);
```

Comment: Note that inside the reducer you're returning `updateLayout` as function, also you need to use `payload` as property inside the object you are sending to dispatch: `payload: {key, value}`

Comment: `state.count.concat(<CreateGraph/>)` <-- you should not store components in redux.  Instead you store the raw data (the component props) and use that data to render the components.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those codes where the more that I look, the more things I see that we can improve!  So I can help you with the redux state not being saved but I also have a lot of other suggestions.

#### Reducer Error

Your reducer for the `UPDATE_LAYOUT` case is all wrong.  You are defining a `function` `updateLayout` which takes a `key` and `value` and returns a state.  Instead of calling that function with the key and value from your `action`, you totally ignore the action and instead you add a property `updateLayout` to your state which includes this function.

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_LAYOUT:            
    return {
        ...state,
        [action.key]: action.value
    }
```

This should fix that reducer case.  We copy all of the existing state properties with `...state` and add/overwrite a property whose name is the `key` from your action and whose value is the `value` from that action.

#### Improving the Action

Why are we passing a `key` in the `action` when the key is always `layout`?  Why not just store the layout in the `payload` property of the action?  (Using the property name `payload` is not required but it is a standard convention).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { 
  return {
    addItem: () => dispatch({type: actionTypes.ADD_GRID_ITEM}),
    updateLayout: (layout) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.UPDATE_LAYOUT, payload: layout})
  }
}
```

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_LAYOUT:            
    return {
        ...state,
        layout: action.payload
    }
```

#### Components in State

Your `state.count` appears to be an array of `<CreateGraph/>` elements.  Though not a fatal error, this is [is not a good idea](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  In general, I would recommend storing the props of the component in the redux state rather than the component itself.  But in this case your component has no props!  So why do we need to store it at all?

It looks to me like the only reason it's there is so that you have an array with the same length as the `layout` array.  This is not necessary.  You can iterate over the `layout` array to get the indexes and and ignore the values.  But I actually think it would be better to use the unique id from the layout elements as the key rather than the array index.

Note: [lodash `_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) is fine, but it's the same as just calling the [built-in array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array (like `value.map()` or `layout.map()`) in this particular case.  The lodash method allows you to use certain shortcut options but you aren't using those so there is no advantage.

You don't need the `state.count` array so you should remove it from your state and your reducer.

#### HTML/JSX Improvements

From [the React Grid Layout docs](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout#usage), it seems like you need to either pass the `layout` object as a prop to the `GridLayout` **or** set the property `data-grid` on the `div`s, but you don't need to do both.  So you can remove one.  I would remove the `data-grid`.

You should not use same the `id` property on more than one HTML element, so you don't want this inside a loop `<div id = 'gridID'>`.

It does not make sense to pass the same `ref` to every item in an array.  This will not work.  I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the refs since you never actually *use* the ref anywhere, so just delete it.

`span` elements render on the same line but `divs` are their own block.  Instead of using a `span` and a `br` you can just use a `div`.

I don't think you need a `key` on the `DashItem` unless the `DashItem` component requires it for some reason. You just need a key on the outermost element in your loop, which you already have.

```
{layout.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.i}>
        <div className='dragHandle'>Drag From Here</div>
        <DashItem>
            <CreateGraph />
        </DashItem>
        <div className='dragHandle'>Drag From Here</div>
    </div>
))}
```